# How to avoid recursive and or infinity loop monogame return function

Tags: c#, monogame

This piece of code is returning on a infinite base how to fix?

```
public GuiElement MoveElement(int x, int y)
{
    GUIRect = new Rectangle(GUIRect.X += x,GUIRect.Y += y,GUIRect.Width,GUIRect.Height);
    return MoveElement(x,y);
}
```

this is where i set the values i have in my Other class

```
        gm.Add(new GuiElement("BackGround"));      

        gm.Add(new GuiElement("Play_Button").MoveElement(150, 50));

        gm.Add(new GuiElement("HighScore_Button"));

        gm.Add(new GuiElement("Quit_Button"));
```

basicly i want a to be able to move some elements using that MoveElement

it creates a infinite loop

An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in giftman.exe

Comment: What's the base case for your recursion? What's the code supposed to do? Please don't revert the edits again.

Comment: its supposed to return some values i have set in another another class

Comment: And the base case for the recursion? You can edit your question to include additional information.

Comment: I don't understand the need for recursion in this case. For your statement to work, your method would have to `return this;`

Comment: i might have missunderstood it however it creates a infinite loop which is what i am trying to get around

Comment: You might use a form of recursion to move child elements of the parent GuiElement (if you have nesting). In this situation, the base case would be an element without any children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use recursion for this (and without a base case, you'll get an infinite loop, like you are).

Just change your method to:

```
public GuiElement MoveElement(int x, int y)
{
    GUIRect = new Rectangle(GUIRect.X += x,GUIRect.Y += y,GUIRect.Width,GUIRect.Height);
    return this;
}
```

Or better yet, add a constructor to set the position of your GuiElement, so you can just call it like this:

```
gm.Add(new GuiElement("Play_Button", 150, 50));
```

Or you can just change your `MoveElement` method to not return anything at all:

```
public void MoveElement(int x, int y)
{
    GUIRect = new Rectangle(GUIRect.X += x,GUIRect.Y += y,GUIRect.Width,GUIRect.Height);
}
```

Then when creating it you can do this:

```
GuiElement playButton = new GuiElement("Play_Button");
playButton.MoveElement(150, 50);
gm.Add(playButton);
```

Comment: that seems to work however it doesnt move it now wierd

Comment: Depending on how you have things set up, you'll likely have to reinitialize some aspects of the `GuiElement`, since all you're doing in `MoveElement` is creating a new rectangle. For example, the renderer might only look at the rectangle once at initialization, and not update itself if the rectangle is replaced. But that's something that'll be specific to your code.

Comment: no i am pretty sure i have solved the loading stuff but it just doesnt want to move at any point

Comment: You can ask a new question about that if you like. I believe this question was only about avoiding the infinite loop.

Comment: nvm i found out so i mark this as solved and btw thanks. i needed to use Find assetname because i need to load in the location when it finds the specific button